# Difference between parameters with double dash and without in C# Selenium webdriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a difference between passing parameters with dashes and without?

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddArguments(new List<string>() 
{ 
   "headless", "no-sandbox", "disable-dev-shm-usage",
   "disable-gpu", "start-maximized", "disable-extensions" 
});
```

and

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
options.AddArguments(new List<string>() 
{ 
   "--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
   "--disable-gpu", "--start-maximized", "--disable-extensions" 
});
```

Comment: Good question! But it was already asked and answered.